# multiple inserts in one line gives error "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS"

Tags: sql, xml, join

I'm attempting to parse through a XML file and i can get most of it to work.  However i need to store this data on a temp table then use that data on a temp table to bring in two additional tables

i need to join in a table called codemaster on my temp table's Code field, then join another table  called codevaluemaster on temp tables CodeValue and finally join criticalitymaster on temp table criticality.

I'm having an issue of creating the temp table right now, i can return my sql parse as a table but not sure how to access it to do the joins on.

so I attempted to make a table and put the values into the table to then start doign my joins on however i' not 100% sure what i am doing.

```
DECLARE @xmlParam XML = '<Profile>
  <Config Name="AA Agent Config 4">
      <StatusIndicator>
          <Code>Biometrics</Code>
          <CodeValue>Deactivated</CodeValue>
          <Criticality>Major</Criticality>
      </StatusIndicator>
  </Config>
  <Config Name="AA Agent Config 4">
      <StatusIndicator>
          <Code>Memory</Code>
          <CodeValue>Out</CodeValue>
          <Criticality>Major</Criticality>
      </StatusIndicator>
  </Config>
  <Config Name="AA Agent Config 4">
      <UsageIndicator>
        <UsageCode>NC</UsageCode>
        <UsageValue>20</UsageValue>
        <UsageTime>4</UsageTime>
        <Condition>Less Than</Condition>
      </UsageIndicator>
  </Config>
  <Config Name="AA Agent Config 4">
      <UsageIndicator>
        <UsageCode>NC</UsageCode>
        <UsageValue>20</UsageValue>
        <UsageTime>4</UsageTime>
        <Condition>Less Than</Condition>
      </UsageIndicator>
  </Config>
</Profile>';

Create table #mergedtemptable
(
Name varchar(max),
Code varchar(max),
CodeValue varchar(max),
Criticality varchar(max),
UsageCode varchar(max),
UsageValue varchar(max),
UsageTime varchar(max),
Condition varchar(max)
)

insert into #mergedtemptable (Name, Code, CodeValue, Criticality, UsageCode, UsageValue, UsageTime, Condition)
values( 
(select 
prof.value('(@Name)[1]', 'varchar(max)'), 
prof.value('(StatusIndicator/Code)[1]', 'varchar(max)'), 
prof.value('(StatusIndicator/CodeValue)[1]', 'varchar(max)'),
prof.value('(StatusIndicator/Criticality)[1]', 'varchar(max)'),
prof.value('(UsageIndicator/UsageCode)[1]', 'varchar(max)'),
prof.value('(UsageIndicator/UsageValue)[1]', 'varchar(max)'),
prof.value('(UsageIndicator/UsageTime)[1]', 'varchar(max)'),
prof.value('(UsageIndicator/Condition)[1]', 'varchar(max)') from @xmlParam.nodes('Profile/Config') as Condition(prof)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
INSERT INTO #mergedtemptable (
    NAME
    ,Code
    ,CodeValue
    ,Criticality
    ,UsageCode
    ,UsageValue
    ,UsageTime
    ,Condition
    )
SELECT prof.value('(@Name)[1]', 'varchar(max)')
    ,prof.value('(StatusIndicator/Code)[1]', 'varchar(max)')
    ,prof.value('(StatusIndicator/CodeValue)[1]', 'varchar(max)')
    ,prof.value('(StatusIndicator/Criticality)[1]', 'varchar(max)')
    ,prof.value('(UsageIndicator/UsageCode)[1]', 'varchar(max)')
    ,prof.value('(UsageIndicator/UsageValue)[1]', 'varchar(max)')
    ,prof.value('(UsageIndicator/UsageTime)[1]', 'varchar(max)')
    ,prof.value('(UsageIndicator/Condition)[1]', 'varchar(max)')
FROM @xmlParam.nodes('Profile/Config') AS Condition(prof)
```

Comment: awesome that got the inserts to work.  Do you know how to iterate through the results of that table to make a second table with all the joins on it? i need to get this one value (i can extrapolate to the rest i need) [CriticalityKey] from criticalitymaster on criticality.codename = criticality, based off the values in the existing row.